# 7 sounds work - 8th and 9th sounds do not work

Tags: android

I am writing a basic sound board. I've got it to my phone and it works fine.
Well for the most part. The first 7 buttons work but the 8th and 9th buttons don't.
My only thought is that it is a memory issue and I should't be creating all 9 mp's at the same time at the start of the program. Perhaps the 8th and 9th are just a little too much for memory.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why the 8th and 9th buttons don't work in the following code? They work in the emulator but crash my phone. I know the code isn't perfect -I'm learning. But a point in the right direction would be great.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
package testing.Variables.Levack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class TestingVariablesActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tt;
    Button messageButton1,messageButton2,messageButton3,messageButton4,messageButton5,messageButton6,messageButton7,messageButton8,messageButton9;

  MediaPlayer mp1,mp2,mp3,mp4,mp5,mp6,mp7,mp8,mp9 = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.baboon);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backoff);
        mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dark6);
        mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dontneedroads);
        mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hua);
        mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hulk);
        mp7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.itsaclipon);
        mp8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ht);
        mp9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.truth1);

   messageButton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton1);
   messageButton1.setOnClickListener(startListener);

   messageButton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton2);
   messageButton2.setOnClickListener(startListener);

   messageButton3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton3);
   messageButton3.setOnClickListener(startListener);

   messageButton4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton4);
   messageButton4.setOnClickListener(startListener);

   messageButton5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton5);
   messageButton5.setOnClickListener(startListener);

   messageButton6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton6);
   messageButton6.setOnClickListener(startListener);

   messageButton7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton7);
   messageButton7.setOnClickListener(startListener);

  messageButton8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton8);
 messageButton8.setOnClickListener(startListener);

   //messageButton9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageButton9);
   //messageButton9.setOnClickListener(startListener);

    }

  private OnClickListener startListener =new OnClickListener()  {
    public void onClick(View v)
    { 

               switch(v.getId()) { 
                   case R.id.messageButton1: 
                        mp1.start();
                        break; 
                   case R.id.messageButton2: 
                         mp2.start();
                         break; 
                   case R.id.messageButton3: 
                        mp3.start();
                        break; 
                   case R.id.messageButton4: 
                        mp4.start();
                        break;  
                   case R.id.messageButton5: 
                        mp5.start();
                        break; 
                   case R.id.messageButton6: 
                        mp6.start();
                        break;  
                   case R.id.messageButton7: 
                        mp7.start();
                        break; 
                   case R.id.messageButton8: 
                        mp8.start();
                        break;
                //   case R.id.messageButton9: 
                       //   mp9.start();
                        //break; 

           } 


        }   
        };









    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues before - the problem seemed to be more sound-specific than anything else. I'd create a collection of MediaPlayers and after the seventh one, it would crash while using certain devices, in my case the Droid X2.

While creating various instances of MediaPlayer on the X2, on the 8th MediaPlayer created Logcat would always catch a `java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1`. When I've tested on several other devices, the error never appears.

A side note, be sure to call `mp1.release();` when you are done with the MediaPlayer - I've tracked down plenty of memory leaks to the failure to release these resources.

Answer (score 0):

If your sounds aren't very long, maybe you should use SoundPool class instead of MediaPlayer solution.
It allows you to manage better many sounds, also simultaneously.

This is the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

This is a good place to start with: http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html

And this is a short article which give some idea about difference between SoundPool and MediaPlayer 
http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/